# issue with capistrano and rake using ext/multistage and rake 0.9.2.2 vs 0.9.2 on the deployed server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I want to bring up a staging environment on a server. I am currenly using capistrano to deploy.

I made the changes for the ext/multistage extension but am getting the following error:

```
# Add RVM's lib directory to the load path.
  * executing "cd /data/sites/staging.domain.com/apps/app/releases/20120501225426 && rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
    servers: ["173.111.158.135"]
    [173.111.158.135] executing command
*** [err :: 173.111.158.135] rake aborted!
*** [err :: 173.111.158.135] Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
*** [err :: 173.111.158.135] 
*** [err :: 173.111.158.135] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
*** [err :: 173.111.158.135] 
    command finished in 1332ms
failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.2' -c 'cd /data/sites/staging.domain.com/apps/app/releases/20120501225426 && rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate'" on 173.111.158.135
```

In my gemfile I have:

```
gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'
```

on my local machine, I get:

```
Tue May 01$ rake -V
rake, version 0.9.2.2
Tue May 01$
```

on server, I have:

```
#rake -V
rake, version 0.9.2

#rake
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

If I run the following:

```
# which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
# which rake
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake
# /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake -V
rake, version 0.9.2
```

The cap error seems a little cryptic. Can anyone help me figure this out? Why would my other cap script be working if I have 0.9.2.2 specified and it only has 9.2? Is there a way that I need to force capistrano to install rake 0.9.2.2 that I am not currently doing and how would I do this?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error comes up usually when you forget to `bundle exec rails something` for instance.  Does capistrano ask/want a bundle command to bundle install these gems maybe?

EDIT:
Yeah I bet your project isn't expecting this: `rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate` but maybe `bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate`.

I'm unsure how you setup your cap however.

This is a rails 3 project yeah?

Comment: hmm... would i run that on server? It looks like the issue is with rake being 0.9.2 and it wanting 0.9.2.2

Comment: That exact message is usually a tell tale sign of `bundle` being missed on a command.  Like if you run `rails g model Blah` on a project that expects a `bundle exec rails g model....`  you'll see this message. So I'm guessing that maybe it's a bundle thing, not a cap thing specifically.

Comment: I think it's a rake version issue but I'm not really sure how to fix it.